# Ruby dynamically assign numbered variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, rspec, variable-assignment

I cant find a similar question, but I'm sure it's out there somewhere so please point me in the direction if it is. I'm writing an rspec test and want to dynamically assign 9 variables.

The long way to do it:

```
@store.owner.item1 = (Faker::Lorem.word)
@store.owner.item2 = (Faker::Lorem.word)
@store.owner.item3 = (Faker::Lorem.word)
@store.owner.item4 = (Faker::Lorem.word)
@store.owner.item5 = (Faker::Lorem.word)
@store.owner.item6 = (Faker::Lorem.word)
@store.owner.item7 = (Faker::Lorem.word)
@store.owner.item8 = (Faker::Lorem.word)
@store.owner.item9 = (Faker::Lorem.word)
```

Something close to what I'm looking for (does not work):

```
(1..9).each { |number| @store.owner.send("item#{number}") = (Faker::Lorem.word) }
```

Comment: I would really recommend setting `@store.owner.items` to be an array and make each element accessible with `@store.owner.items[0]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(1..9).each { |number| @store.owner.send("item#{number}=", Faker::Lorem.word) }
```

you can send `item6` or `item6=` both are methods of `owner`.  If you send a method that needs its own parameter (as `item6=` does) then the next parameter of the `send` method is the parameter to send to the method.